# InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool.

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am doing test on a small percona machine on centos 7. Yesterday I tried to restart mysql server but it took too long nearly an hour. So I notice in the log this

```
InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool.
```

After that I ran this query

```
select 
'innodb', 
concat(round(raw/1024/1024,1),'MB') as totalLen, 
@@innodb_buffer_pool_size as innodb_buffer_pool_size, 
round(raw-(1.1*@@innodb_buffer_pool_size),0) as 'Suggested change' 
from ( 
select sum(index_length) + sum(data_length) as raw 
from information_schema.tables 
where engine ='innodb' 
) sum 

innodb 
totalLen 
innodb_buffer_pool_size 
Suggested change 
innodb 
167.8MB 
134217728 
28259123
```

I notice the suggested change is less then the current settings? Next to over come this I read `http://www.speedemy.com/how-to-speed-up-mysql-restart/`. 
Its suggested set global innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 0. What worries be will it have impact on the db such as corrupting the db? How much of innodb_io_capacity is to be set? What else should I do to overcome is the ib log should also be increase to help?

Comment: Huh?  The "suggested change" is to increase the buffer_pool; "less than current settings" seems irrelevant.  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @RickJames currently I have only 2gb ram its a very small virtual machine just for test. I did not increase the ram let it as default. I dont get you when you said is to increase the buffer pool. Will the increase help in the shutdown and start up? Should I put the show variable from the server?

Comment: I don't _know_ whether increasing the buffer_pool will help.  But for only 2GB of RAM, it should not be raised past 500M.  (And that may be too much if other apps are running on the same server.)

Comment: @RickJames yes there are other apps running e.g. the web server etc.Maybe I will increase to just 500 mbps but the issue it's taking too long to restart. So will I need to set this innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 0? Normally what else could be effecting could it be the ib log file need to be increase too?

Comment: It seems 'wrong' to set the pct to 0, but I don't have a good feel.  If the server has low activity, there is little need to increase the log_file_size.

Comment: @RickJames actually there is quite a number of insert being done though for testing purpose around 200 in a minute. So what best your suggestion.

Comment: 200 per _second_ would be 'fast', and might need some special treatment.  To dig deeper, I would need to look at all the tunables.  See instructions [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis)

Comment: @RickJames I have pasted 3 things in the pastebin that is https://pastebin.com/U5BrLDyQ(show variables), https://pastebin.com/38vQ9kRf(SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;) and https://pastebin.com/AixfGhyY (my config). I hope to learn from your analysis and improve my skills too. Also you will be able to advice on why it takes too long to restart.

Comment: Ouch... "This page is no longer available. It has either expired, been removed by its creator, or removed by one of the Pastebin staff." -- on the first two links.  (Maybe pastebin is no longer a good place for such??)

Comment: @RickJames can I sent your email if that is ok with you? Maybe you can drop an email message to my email registered here.

Comment: (I failed to find where it is registered.)  This should get to me: se at rjweb dot org

Comment: @RickJames I have sent email from my gmail account. Hope you have received it. Thank you once again.

Comment: I responded via email.  A few settings should be changed, but I can't say that any of them definitely affect the page_cleaner.  I await your testing of them.

Comment: Please post to pastebin.com 
current complete my.cnf/ini and php.ini (if used)
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  for analysis of reasons for waiting for page_cleaner to finish,

Comment: @Wilson it's not happening now but could it be a bug

Comment: Anything could be a bug, not likely though..  Yours was probably related to load on system at the time.If you still have files e-mailed in Oct, they would be fine.  If not, they are quick to create.

Comment: @WilsonHauck can I email you easier though yes I do have the files which I emailed to rick.

Comment: Email to   wlhauck at aol <dot> com  Thanks